# Further explanation of $\sum^\infty_\mathrm{n=0} a_nx^n$ [Beyond (0,1)]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is related to a question asked earlier, but I'm trying to gain a deeper understand of how $\sum^\infty_\mathrm{n=0} a_nx^n$ functions.

Say that the series is **not** restricted to $0 ≤ a_n ≤ 1$

Suppose that for all integers $n ≥ 0$ and $0 ≤ a_n ≤ M$ where $M > 0$.

Additionally, suppose that $0 ≤ x < 1$.

Given these conditions, what can be said about
$\sum^\infty_\mathrm{n=0} a_nx^n$?

Edit: Based on comments, it seem that $\sum^\infty_\mathrm{n=0} a_nx^n$ ≤ $M * \sum^\infty_\mathrm{n=0} x^n$ because $a_n$ has the new upper bound of M. Explanation of this equivalency would be great.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n < M \times \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = M \times \frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: I'm assuming you're basing this on the respective upper bounds. Is there a reason it's a strictly less than equivalency?

Comment: To Bob Mcdonald : Good catch, my carelessness.  The comment should read $\cdots \leq M \times \cdots$.